# How to bring my Swift 3.2 application to front

Tags: ios, swift3

Here is an simple Swifter application in Swift 3.2 and xCode9.
Its working.
But I would write this application when this app is in background, then it bringing to front and I will see the standard white screen.

What is the best way for this idea?

```
import UIKit
import AudioToolbox
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import Swifter

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let server = HttpServer()
        server["/hello"] = {
            var queryParamsInfo = ""
            for (name, value) in $0.queryParams {
                queryParamsInfo += "\(name) -> \(value)<br/>"
            }
            AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
            return .ok(.html("<h3>You asked for \(queryParamsInfo)</h3>"))
        }
        do {
            try server.start()
            print("Server is started")
            while true {
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("Error!")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do?  Your app can only enter the foreground if the user taps the icon or a notification, or if it is called by its app URL scheme.

Comment: So, I will trying tell clarify: my app is starting, user is sending background it, somebody call my app's Swifter model with /hello and this case I would bring to front my application to iPhone. Sorry for my pure English!

Comment: Your app cannot run a http server when it is in the background. You can register a urlscheme for your app that can be used to bring it tot he foreground.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not possible on iOS**. An application can only enter the foreground if

- The user taps the app icon
- The user taps a notification
- The user brings the app to the foreground from the multitasking menu
- The app is opened by another app (using URL Schemes)

You **can not** bring your app to the foreground programatically.